# What's the proper way to select certain fields in a query when you use Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I read the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) that describes how to solve the issue with extracting certain fields of an object found by id. I've tried to write a similar code, but the output assigned to the *user* variable includes all fields of a single element.

```
export const getUser = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const userFetchesOwnData = req.app.locals.userId === id;
    let user: any;
    if (req.app.locals.isAuth && userFetchesOwnData) {
      user = await User.findById(
        id,
        "email username age sex location summary"
      ).exec();
    } else {
      user = await User.findById(
        id,
        " username age sex location summary"
      ).exec();
    }
    console.log(user);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "User fetched",
      user,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: The query looks fine correct. The user variable should have all the selected fields + _id field. If you need to exclude _id field then need to add `-_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specifically query fields in a Mongoose object by comma separated values.

```
User.findById(id).select("_id, email, username, age, sex, location, summary").then(...)
```

Comment: The query still returns full data.

Comment: What version of Mongoose are you using?

Comment: @BriahPhelps, It is 5.11.19.